# Setting Scala Sans font as the `mathrm` font

Tags: fonts, mathspec, mathrm

I am trying to set `mathrm` font to be Scala Sans. What I have done is the following,

```
\usepackage[quiet]{mathspec}

\newfontfamily{\scala}{ScalaSans}[Path =scalasans/,
Extension = .otf,
UprightFont = *-RegularLF,
BoldFont = *-BoldLF,
ItalicFont = *-RegularLFItalic]

\setmathrm{\scala}
```

It's not working and I am not sure how to set Scala Sans as the `mathrm` font (though I have been able to use the font in the text). How to do it? I am using `XeLaTeX`.

Moreover, I am using overleaf. So, I have uploaded the font `.otf` files in overleaf. Please describe a general method so that if I have any other custom fonts then the method can be applied as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You call `\setmathrm` this way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[quiet]{mathspec}

\setmathrm{ScalaSans}[ Path = scalasans/,
                       Extension = .otf,
                       UprightFont = *-RegularLF,
                       BoldFont = *-BoldLF,
                       ItalicFont = *-RegularLFItalic ]

\begin{document}
\( \mathrm{Scala Sans }\mathbf{Bold }\mathit{Italic} \)
\end{document}
```

See [§4.4](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/unicodetex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.pdf#1a) of the `fontspec` manual.  (You might have been thinking of setting an operator font.)

To load Scala Sans twice, as a body font and in math mode, but write its options only once, use `\defaultfontfeatures[ScalaSans]`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[quiet]{mathspec}

\defaultfontfeatures[ScalaSans]{
  Path = scalasans/,
  Extension = .otf,
  UprightFont = *-RegularLF,
  BoldFont = *-BoldLF,
  ItalicFont = *-RegularLFItalic }        

\newfontfamily\scala{ScalaSans}
\setmathrm{ScalaSans}

\begin{document}
\( \mathrm{Scala Sans }\mathbf{Bold }\mathit{Italic} \)
\end{document}
```

You can also save this `\defaultfontfeatures` command in a file named `ScalaSans.fontspec`, and `fontspec` will then load the correct options for your installation whenever you load `ScalaSans`.